# Check if an app is installed on the device

Tags: applications, adb, python

I'm trying to use the package name and determine the apk path of an app to check if my app is installed in the device.

```
pathCmd = './adb shell pm path ' + packageName


pathData = os.popen(pathCmd,"r")


for pathInfo in pathData:

    print pathInfo 

    if not pathInfo:
        print "App not found on the device"

    else:
        print "App found on the device"
```

This doesn't give me the list of apps that are not installed. Any idea whats wrong with my script?

Comment: Before people vote to close, this doesn't seem to be a clear-cut development question. While it's true that he is developing a script, it's also an ADB question. It's essentially something you could do in bash or in a Windows batch. I'll let the community decide if this is off-topic or not.

Comment: Consider to accept your own answer if there is no other answer, and if it solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick guys.

```
pathCmd = './adb shell pm path ' + packageName
result = os.popen(pathCmd).read()
if result:
    print "App found on the device"
else:
    print "App not found on the device"
```

This give system output as string and looks for string length to confirm the presence of an app in the device. Its usually an empty string that is received for a package name that doesn't exist in the device.